# Tish'a Ushloshim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred thirty nine?

### תשעה ושלושים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 339? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 339, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

By the authority vested in me as the forger of this question, I request answers that do not do lazy gematria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There are 339 words total in the closing lines of the benedictions of the three *amida* prayers on a weekday.](/a/3713)